# Radeon Ring stalled (16.04) (Live-USB)

Tags: graphics, live-usb, radeon

I am new to Linux, I wanted to test Ubuntu 16.04 for myself. I have problem similar to one mentioned in this thread (["radeon: ring 0 test failed" on boot ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457391/radeon-ring-0-test-failed-on-boot-ubuntu-14-04)), but this is happening every single time I want to launch Ubuntu (I've checked also Elementary OS and Solus, almost same effect), so I can't change nothing in Linux (it is still not installed just live from pendrive). Linux is booting, then shows some cracked screen with parts of misplaced last Windows session. Since this is not installed OS I can't change drivers (that was mentioned as working method), actually I dont have chance to run Ubuntu even for a second.

I have Asrock H77 Pro4-M Motherboard and I have Primary Graphic Adapter in BIOS set as PCI Express, as I've read it should automatically disable switching GPU. My graphic card is Club3D Radeon HD 7870 XT jokerCard.

Edit: Is there any possibility to get an Ubuntu release with build-in Catalyst? I see some people have very similar problem. I understand that using 16.04 is impossible on my machine, but there can still be possibility of older version with build in Catalyst, at least I hope so.

Thanks if someone wants to help me, hope I can try Ubuntu on my current PC.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-ati
```

Ref:
[radeon ring 0 stalled - Login GUI never opens](https://askubuntu.com/questions/869623/radeon-ring-0-stalled-login-gui-never-opens/869660#869660)

Answer (score 0):

I had the Dell standard AMD FirePro W2100, which was not supported by the latest AMD Linux drivers.  Upgraded the hardware to a more recent AMD and haven't had this problem since.