# radeon ring 0 stalled - Login GUI never opens

Tags: boot, 16.04, drivers, graphics, radeon

I recently noticed that I am no longer able to launch a GUI on Ubuntu 16.04.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have ran `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` to make sure I wasn't behind on any packages.

When I reboot I just see this repetitive error message (although I can still ssh fine):

```
[ 1231.958791] radeon 0000:01:05.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 1122500msec
[ 1231.959218] radeon 0000:01:05.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x000000000000000f last fence id 0x0000000000000017 on ring 0)
```

Here is my graphics card info:
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'

```
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS780L [Radeon 3000]
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd RS780L [Radeon 3000]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

After fishing around for a few hours I came across this package that ended up fixing the problem. It was not installed, however it was apparently not needed a few months ago.

This fixed it for me:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-ati
```

Comment: This package actually caused be not to be able to login (I would put in my credentials) and then it would look like it was loading in, but then just cycle back to login. I actually removed it `sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-video-ati` and now everything is working