# Reinstalling (ubuntu, lubuntu, xubuntu) stalls

Tags: system-installation, freeze

I'm trying to reinstall Ubuntu and my laptop freezes.

I had Ubuntu on there, and I wanted to try a light weight Ubuntu, so I first tried to install xubuntu that didn't work.

Then I tried lubuntu that didn't work.

Then I tried to put ubuntu back on there and that didn't work.

I thought it might be because my USB sticks are old or it might be the hard drive.  So I bought a couple of new USB sticks and a new hard drive.  That didn't work (I mean the hardware functioned but didn't resolve the problem).

I've tried it with a network cable plugged in and without a network cable plugged in.

I've added a picture at the bottom of this question showing where it freezes.

I left my laptop overnight and it had progressed to almost work.  The graphical user interface was running with the mouse working, but there was no window with all the options to install anything.  (Sorry I didn't get a photo of that, just imagine a empty desktop with no icons, no menus, no windows.)

My computer is an old HP laptop RMN: TPN-W121 (I think it's about 5 or maybe 6 years old).

What could I try next?

[image]

Comment: You've not provided any release details; which lets us know the *software stack* you're talking about. Supported releases of Lubuntu all use the `calamares` installer, but older releases use two other installers - without release details we can't know which you tried.  It looks more from your picture that your system didn't boot it; so did you verify the ISO as being valid? and your write of ISO to installation media?  (using the appropriate method for your *unstated* release?)  That's what I'd confirm first (*using another box to verify the media write if that box won't boot it*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Radeon Ring stalled (16.04) (Live-USB)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815975/radeon-ring-stalled-16-04-live-usb)   *this may or may not apply as you didn't provide release specifics*

Comment: I used the latest version of Ubuntu, Lubuntu and Xubuntu which I downloaded yesterday everything is 22.04.

Comment: With the verification of the ISO, I haven't verified it,  However I have downloaded 3 different ISO's Ubuntu, Lubuntu and Xubuntu.  And I've used multiple different USB sticks in different attempts including band new USB sticks I bought yesterday.  The chances of three different ISO's all being bad when they are sourced separately is rather low.

Comment: If you use the same method to write the ISO to thumb-drive (media), your theory is missing a very significant potential flaw.  I write hundreds of ISOs to thumb-drive per year, and about 5-8% fail because thumb-drives are *cheap* media made to cost & thus errors occur. They're a convenient consumable media.

Comment: Yes, 8% is a high failure rate so if I try this 3 times the chance of all three times failing is 0.08 to the power of 3.  Which is 0.000512 which in percentages is 0.0512% chance of all 3 failing based on the 8% failure rate.  (If the failure rate was 5% then the chance of all three failing is 0.0125%).  I tried this with 3 different versions of Linux Ubuntu, Lubuntu and Xubuntu, but I have actually tried it with a range of different USB sticks, I have lost count of how many USB sticks I've actually tried.

Comment: The write of an ISO to media us what matters, if done incorrectly you'd expect 100% failure rates which is what you got. You've provided nothing that rules out user-procedure-errors; no clues as to how you wrote, what validation you performed, if you used appropriate software for the *unstated* release in your question. Ubuntu ISOs have varied in recent releases & older software cannot write modern Ubuntu ISOs of 21.04, 21.10 & 22.04 correctly so if using software designed for say older/different 20.04 (which differed) and didn't  *clone* - errors are expected 100% of the time due changes.

Comment: I've got a tower with Ubuntu 22.04 installed and I used the Startup Disk Creator application to setup all my USB sticks.  I've never had a problem with this tower.

Comment: Your problem description is unclear. Is it the installation process that 'stalls', or the boot of the newly installed system? 'Didn't work' is so vague as to be useless.

Comment: If only 6 years old like my "new" system from 2016, it is UEFI. Have you updated UEFI to latest available. HPs often need firmware update. And if new drive is SSD, check if it has latest firmware. Be sure to boot in UEFI boot mode. Many, for whatever reason, find using different flash drive, different tool to create installer, or different USB port then find installer works. Try mkusb, Rufus or others.

Answer (score 0):

- did you do a clean install each time? IE: reformat drive.
- did you try an older version of Ubuntu (given that you said the computer is older)?
- it's possible there is a hardware fault... not likely  but possible.

It looks like a graphics problem but if the machine worked before it should still work but who knows. I think 22.04 now uses Wayland by default - that could be the problem if a previous Ubuntu version worked. I'm guessing.

Comment: I was able to format the hard drive at the beginning of everything.  But since then I haven't been able to get anything on the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

I got my computer to work.

I gave up on Ubuntu, Lubuntu and Xubuntu.

I looked for a different distro of Linux that was lightweight and not derived from Ubuntu.

It worked immediately with no problems at all.